# Ionic 3: Download and replace file directly in `file:///android_asset/www/assets/i18n`

Tags: cordova, ionic3, angular5

I am trying to update translation file directly by downloading and storing it in application directory.
Below is my code to download and replace file,

```
private downloadLanguageFile(url: string, lang: string) {
    const appDir = this.file.applicationDirectory;
    let promise = this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'}).toPromise();
    promise.then((downloadedFile: any) => {
        this.file.writeFile(appDir, `${lang}.json`, downloadedFile, {replace: true})
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log("error writing file", error);
            })
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("Download language file failed", error);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

but instead of saving file in that directory it is throwing this error:

> FileError {code: 1, message: "NOT_FOUND_ERR"} code: 1 message:
>
> "NOT_FOUND_ERR"
>
> **proto**: Object

Code works perfectly when I change the file directory to dataDirectory.
Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Note:
Copy operation is allowed for file and directory from `applicationDirectory` to anyother directory, but the reverse is not allowed.

Comment: Changing the dir to this.file.externalDataDirectory  also works